# Set Color QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, colors

I'm working with the QTextEdit class. 
I would like to set a predefinite color for my edit block. 
When I open the textEdit and I begin to write something, I want to write the characters with a color that is different from zero. 
I've tried to insert the following code, in the costructor of the class:

```
ui->textEdit->setTextColor(Qt::red)
```

but it doesn't work. 
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setTextColor you have should work fine - QColor(255,0,0) and Qt::red are the same thing. Tried it and works fine.
[image]

OR maybe style sheets would help

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { color: red; } ");
```

https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html

Comment: The way you have should also be working fine, check my example above.

Comment: It's perfect. Thanks so much

Comment: I'm sorry but at first, I haven't seen your first example